# Download with the bash or Python while keeping the directory tree/structure

Tags: linux, bash, python, scripting

I have a list of files that I need to download such as

```
www.domain.com/files/archive.zip
www.domain.com/img/icon.ico
www.domain.com/files/backup/archive.zip
www.domain.com/backup/img/icon.ico
www.domain.com/archive.zip
```

meaning that i got name collision in this list of files so i need to keep the directory structure intact and recreate it while downloading this, i haven't found nothing even similar to this in the Python urllib and I don't know of any linux tool that can be good for this.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Where exactly do you see the problem doing this with bash? - I mean: mkdir files; cd files; wget www.domain.com/files/archive.zip; mkdir ../img/; cd ../img/ wget ....

Comment: @SimonStrasser at first i was trying with python, with the bash i just don't know a name for a good tool ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for wget - it will by default recreate the same directory structure on your localhost as on the webserver it's fetching stuff from.

Comment: thanks, wget is able to read from a text file the list of files to download ?

Comment: Yes. It's quite versatile. There's info at http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: `wget -x -i file.txt` does the trick, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

wget can do this pretty easily:

```
wget -x -nH http://www.domain.com/files/archive.zip
```

This will create the local directory `files` and download archive.zip into it.

Comment: ok, thanks, but i was handling this starting from a text file http://serverfault.com/questions/462260/download-with-the-bash-or-python-while-keeping-the-directory-tree-structure#comment509255_462264